# How can I point gcc and g++ to the gnu compiler collection?

Tags: xcode, homebrew, development, gcc

I want to use the gnu compiler collection instead of the x-code compiler to compile some bioinformatics tools on the mac, which did compile on Linux but fails to build on macOS.

I did install homebrew

```
$ brew install gcc

$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 gcc

$ /usr/local/bin/gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

However, calling gcc without the path still points to clang.

```
$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
```

How can I point gcc and g++ to the gnu compiler collection?

Comment: Did you open a new Terminal tab after installing `gcc`? What does `type gcc` say, and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @nohillside
Before reopening the terminal type gcc was:
$ type gcc 
gcc is hashed (/usr/bin/gcc)

reopening the terminal did help indeed. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mess around with getting gcc on your PATH. You don't point g++ to the compiler you want.

You alter your build system - usually a Makefile, CMake, autoconf or Xcode to build using the C compiler you want. (This also allows different projects to use different compilers)

Comment: What's so scary about customizing `PATH`? Setting your own `PATH` isn't "messing around". For the sake of efficiency, isn't pointing `g++` to the compiler you want the best behavior? With the most frequently used `g++` in your PATH, you can still alter your build system to use any other C compiler you want. Isn't this the most convenient way?

Comment: It is not scary but the point is when building c++ programs you don't rely on the path for gcc. You control the environment via your build script - e.g. makefile, Xcode project, CMAKE file etc and not the PATH. It would be best if the default was to fail and you explicitly set which compiler to use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I see your point. Maybe because I usually don't work with many different compilers, I do prefer a desired default gcc in the path. This preference also pushed me toward `MacPorts`, even though I use both.

Comment: Having just one C compiler was a feature of NeXTStep and early Linux before clang existed, other Unixes usually had at their own C plus gcc

Answer (score 1):

The shell hashes (caches) paths to binaries. So if you run `gcc` before installing a new version in a different path, it will still use the previous/remembered version. To fix, either clear the stored path (check the `hash` command in the man page of your shell)  or simply open a new Terminal tab.